# Parse xml longblob from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I having problems to read a column type longblob that containing a file XML. If I entry to phpmyadmin and I make click at column myxml (type longblob) this download a file .bin that contain a XML, but if make a SELECT to my column myxml whit PHP and  MySql, this only shows a white space.

My code:

```
$dbquery = $data -> prepare("SELECT TABLE_1.ISSUEDDATE, TABLE_1.TOTAL, TABLE_1.ISSUERRFC, TABLE_1.RECEIVERRFC, TABLE_1.UUID, TABLE_1.FOLIO, TABLE_2.BYTES, CONVERT(BYTES USING utf8) AS XML FROM DOCUMENT TABLE_1 INNER JOIN FILE TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.XML_ID = TABLE_2.ID WHERE TABLE_1.ID = 244938 ORDER BY TABLE_1.ID");
$dbquery -> execute();               

while($rows = $dbquery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
$rowsxml = new SimpleXMLElement($rows['XML']);
print_r($rowsxml);
endwhile;
```

Comment: Should you be using `CONVERT(TABLE_2.MYXML USING utf8)`?

Comment: Sorry, its true,.  But now I only can to get the first node, I need to take the rest nodes. Is posible?

Comment: you should be able to use a foreach on `$rowsxml->children()` to get to the other nodes. You can do that recursively to get to the children of those nodes.

Comment: I have that to pass one param to children()? Whit it ($rowsxml->children()), I get the same results (only one node, the first).